# Reference to multiple bounds generic receiver extension function in Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin, kotlin-extension

Has an extension function

`fun <T> T.doSomething() where T: A, T: B`

If there only one generic bound `A`, I can use syntax `(A::doSomething)(instanceOfA)` to reference to the function, but how to do this with multiple bounds?

---

Example:

`interface A`, `interface B`, and a extension function bounded with both interfaces `fun <T> T.doSomething() where T: A, T: B`.

Now I manage to "override" `doSomething` if a class extends additional `interface C`, like `class X: A, B, C`:

1. Declare another extension function `fun <T> T.doSomething() where T: A, T: B, T: C`
2. Declare `doSomething()` inside class `X`

If I use `doSomething()` in both "override" function directly will cause endless recursion. How can I reference to original `fun <T> T.doSomething() where T: A, T: B`(like `super.doSomething()`)?

Comment: pls give a clear example of what you want to achieve. where do A and B come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit ugly, but

```
fun <T> T.doSomething() where T: A, T: B = ...

// calls the first version of doSomething
fun <T> T.doSomethingHelper() where T: A, T: B = this.doSomething()

@JvmName("doSomethingElse")
fun <T> T.doSomething() where T: A, T: B, T: C = ... // use doSomethingHelper() here
```

Without `@JvmName` I get

> java.lang.ClassFormatError: Duplicate method name&signature in class file Simplest_versionKt